# Getting the source of a webpage with Selenium

Tags: selenium, web

After the browser finishes loading a page, I can right-click on the page, and select 'Save Page As'. There, I get an 'HTML Only' option as well as 'Web Page, Complete' option. Of course, the second option creates a directory (to save all the .js files etc.), but interestingly, the main source file is also different. That is, 'HTML Only' creates a file named (e.g.) `site.html`, while the 'Complete' option creates `site.html` as well as a `site/` directory. The two `site.html` files are different. Why is that?

Anyway, I try to fetch (with Selenium) the second file, that is, I need to get a file identical to the `site.html` file saved by the 'Complete' option. It doesn't work. I get a different version of the html source file (I use Selenium's page_source method).

If there's a way to get it, in an automated way, without Selenium, I'm also interested.

Comment: Along with tagging _selenium_ you may like to tag _html_ as well

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's the way Selenium works. It gets the wrong version of the source file. I'd like it to work correctly.

Comment: any JS dynamic updates to the DOM would not be reflected in "page source".   (in the browser... never used Selenium's page source method but I'd assume it would be the same)  If you're wanting to work with raw HTML instead of using webelements, you might look into "Panda" for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a non-Selenium way of downloading html files using the `requests` library. Here's a method that will download a file to a folder of your choice:

```py
import os
import requests

def download_file_to(file_url, destination_folder, new_file_name=None):
    if new_file_name:
        file_name = new_file_name
    else:
        file_name = file_url.split("/")[-1]
    r = requests.get(file_url)
    file_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, file_name)
    with open(file_path, "wb") as code:
        code.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Not good... it'll download the very first version of the source HTML, before any JS changes to it, and much before any AJAX changes (and possibly other things I've missed).  I noted that that there's a difference between the sources that the browser can save. I'm not sure why thsese differences occur, but if they're due to dynamic JS or so, then your script will yield the wrong version. Instead of requests you could use requests_html, which will take into accout dynamic JS, and then do some sleep() or wait() to count for the AJAX, but these still don't give the final version of the HTML...

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of getting the page source with Selenium is:

`driver.page_source`

Is that the source you're looking for?

Comment: As I noted in my question, that's exactly the method I'm using. It does indeed give an HTML source file, but that file is different from what my browser saves.